# Find the solution of the trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am asked to obtain the solutions of $2\cos x-1+3\sec x=0$ without using the calculator.

first I simplified it to $$\begin{aligned}2\cos x-1+\frac{3}{\cos x}&=0\\2\cos^{2} x-\cos x+3&=0\end{aligned}$$
I solved like this,
I let $\cos x=u$ and solved the equation,

$$\begin{aligned}2u^{2}-u+3&=0\\u&=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{(-1)^{2}-4(2)(3)}}{2(2)}\\&=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-24}}{4}\\&=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-23}}{4}\end{aligned}$$

This are complex values values, means $\cos x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-23}}{4}$, how can I obtain the values of $x$ now?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the mechanical way (also know as the "I don't really understand what I'm doing" way") is to then write "$x = \pm \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-23}}{4} \right) + 2 \pi k$, for any integer $k$."  Alternatively, since you've graphed cosine, you know that it's always real-valued (in your class), so there is no such $x$.

Comment: If the problem read $2\cos x - 1 - 3\sec x = 0$, then $x = \pi$ would be a solution.